# Probability of at least one success in large sample

Tags: probability

I toss 1000 *unfair* coins. I wish to calculate the probability that out of the outcomes of the 1000 tosses, at least one head will be obtained. The probability of getting head in any one toss is 0.03125.

I know how to solve this with fair coins where each of the two outcomes is equally likely. But I have no idea where to begin when the probabilities are unequal.

Comment: [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  More specifically for this problem, you can find the probability that you get all tails and subtract that result from one to find probability of at least one head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of heads among the total $n$ tosses of the unfair coin. You are interested in computing $\Pr\left(X > 0\right)$. Since $X$ is certainly non-negative, we have
$$
   \Pr(X>0) = \Pr(X \geqslant 0) - \Pr(X=0) = 1 - \Pr(X=0)
$$
The event $\{X=0\}$ means that all of $n$ *independent* tosses resulted in the tail, i.e. $\Pr(X=0) = \left(1-p\right)^n$, thus
$$
   \Pr(X>0) = 1 - \left(1-p\right)^n
$$

Comment: What is *p* here? Is its value 0.03125?

Comment: Yes, $p$ is the probability of getting a head in one toss.